# What's the right way to go from one form to another?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I am doing a school java project using the NetBeans IDE. It includes some basic database manipulations. We were taught at school to use the following for linking one form to another:

```
new <form_name>().setVisible(true)
```

But this seem to slow down the whole application and there is a small lag for going from one form to another.   I heard that using `JDialog` boxes is a solution to this problem. 
So what's the right way to do it?

Comment: So what have you tried with JDialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to not swap in and out of different JFrames. How many professional applications such as word processors do you use that do this that throw different windows at the user? Better to use one main JFrame and swap *views* (usually JPanels) in it via a CardLayout and occasionally show a dependent Window as a dialog when needed, especially when you need to get information in a modal way.

Answer (score 2):

> some basic database manipulations. .. But this seem to slow down the whole application

Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

(But also see @Hovercraft's advice re. `CardLayout`..)